# Multiprocess Process Python3 - Return DataFrames

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I have a large function that needs to be run parallel to save computing time. The function takes a name and list and returns a dataframe with the computation results. 
I need to have each dataframe returned and saved into a list(or something). 
I can get the parallel to run using PROCESS but it returns a cumulative dataframe. How can I get the dataframe from each process without all being additive. 
Hence:

```
DF1 = A B
      1 2
      2 4


DF2 = A B
      1 3
      5 6
```

What I get back is:

```
DF1 = A B
      1 2
      2 4

DF2 = A B
      1 2
      2 4
      1 3
      5 6
```

I have pasted my example code below:
Thank you in advance - I cannot seem to figure this one out..

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    SectorA = ["AAPL", "ATVI", "BIDU"]
    SectorB = ['AA','IBM','UAL']
    sectors = [SectorA,SectorB, Tech_Sector, TransP_Sector]
    sectorsNames = ['SectorA', 'SectorB']

    ######################################################################
    procs = []
    #proc = Process(target=RUN_Function)  # instantiating without any argument
    #procs.append(proc)
    #proc.start()

    # instantiating process with arguments
    for name, sec in itt.zip_longest(sectorsNames, sectors):
        info("My Main")
        proc = Process(target=RUN_Function, args=(name,sec))
        procs.append(proc)
        procs.start()
        #proc.join()

    '''
    for mpos in procs:
        print("Positions for the following: ".format(mpos))
    '''

    print("Finished")

    proc.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with multiprocessing, but maybe AsyncIO can be interested, as an example

**Code**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from asyncio import ensure_future, gather, run
from json import dumps


async def calculate(data):
    tasks = list()
    result = dict()
    temp = None

    for df in data:
        task = ensure_future(calculate_one(df, data[df]))
        tasks.append(task)

        temp = await gather(*tasks)

    for element in temp:
        result[element['df']] = element['ds']

    return result


async def calculate_one(df, dataset):
    result = dict()
    result['df'] = df
    result['ds'] = list()
    for element in dataset:
        result['ds'].append(element + '-processed')

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':

    src_data = {'df1': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1'],
                'df2': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2']}

    res = run(calculate(src_data))

    print(dumps(res, indent=4))
```

This source code can be found [here](https://github.com/caa06d9c/Examples/blob/master/Python/basic/asyncio/calculate_in_parallel/run.py)

**Result**

```
{
    "df1": [
        "a1-processed",
        "b1-processed",
        "c1-processed",
        "d1-processed"
    ],
    "df2": [
        "a2-processed",
        "b2-processed",
        "c2-processed",
        "d2-processed"
    ]
}
```

Your example is not very clear, so if you need data from other data frames for processing you can use global variables or you can put all scr_data into calculate_one and use indexes.

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dmitrii,

I FINALLY solved this.

I was overlooking the .append().

This should be excluded and a .close() should be added after the loop. Hope this helps someone else.

```
for name, sec in zip(sectorsNames, sectors):
    #info("My Main")
    proc = Process(target=RUN_Function, args=(name,sec))
    #procs.append(proc)---#EXCLUDE THIS
    proc.start()
#procs.append(proc)
proc.close() #ADD THE CLOSE
```